# Why my value is not passing into secondViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, segue

I want to pass simple String from oneVC to secondVC. I'm new to iOS.

1. I declared String nameOfFilm.
2. When I'm clicking on CollectionViewItem I'm downloading JSON, taking one value of it(String) and assign it to nameOfFilm. Then I'm starting segue to the secondVC.
3. in the PrepareForSegue method with proper identifier I compare the secondVC value to the nameOfFlim.(nextScene.name = nameOfFilm)

In the result, when the secondVC comes in, nextScene.name is empty.enter image description here
JSON i parsed properly. I think it may be mismatch in time and some functions are too fast. What is causing the problem?

```
var nameOfFilm = String()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    INDEX_NUMBER_BEFORE = indexPath.row
    let filmID = arrayWithID[INDEX_NUMBER_BEFORE]
    downloadFilm(url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(filmID)\(key)&append_to_response=videos,images")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheDetail", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toTheDetail" {
        let nextScene = segue.destination as! FilmDetailViewController
        nextScene.name = nameOfFilm
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. Show code right in your question.

Comment: @matt thanks for pointing me that. Already Edited.

Comment: and can you please post the code of downloadFilm method , need to check the data operation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here will be that downloadFilm will be an asynchronous task that occurs in the background and takes some time to make the request and respond with the value that you need.

Your downloadFilm function should accept a callback so that you can wait for the response value and then perform an action based on that response, a typical way of using this would be something like:

```
downloadFilm(url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(filmID)\(key)&append_to_response=videos,images") { filmName in 
    self.nameOfFilm = filmName
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheDetail", sender: self)
}
```

To do this you would need to update your downloadFilm function, so that its similar to this...

```
func downloadFilm(url: String, completion: @escaping (_ filmName: String) -> Void) {
   // do work here to setup network request
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      // parse response and get name
      completion(name)
   }
}
```

[Here](https://cocoacasts.com/what-do-escaping-and-noescaping-mean-in-swift-3/) is a guide on Swift completion handlers that will help understand the concept.